# Good practice to divide items into groups

Tags: interaction-design

[image]I am currently working on an enterprise project, and I've come across a puzzle like this.

There are a range of items (about 10) I need to group. What I do is like a wizard in a single page, letting a user pick several to form the first group by checkbox, and let them pick from the rest to form the second group, and loop on.
Of course it is not an elegant way, but currently I cant figure out a better one.

Our system is little bit old fashioned, so please don't use too much rich interaction.

Comment: Are you able to supply a screenshot / mockup of the current screen?

Comment: mockup updated.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a matrix of radio buttons for this. The group titles could also be editable and you can add a "+" button or something to be able to dynamically add more groups if necessary.
[image: simple radio button matrix]

Comment: It looks in the OP that each item is supposed to be able to have several coverages. With this solution each item would be able to be assigned one coverage, or a coverage could only be assigned to one single item, because it's radio buttons.

Comment: Ok, I'm not really sure whether I understood "let them pick **from the rest** to form the second group" correct, but this sounds like they can only be in one. Anyway, you may also use checkboxes if that is not the case.

Comment: I believe that if you use checkboxes instead your solution is on the right track. One of the problems with the solution designed by the OP is the unnecessary repetition of descriptive text just adding to the bulk. With a solution similar to yours the coverages could be described by the column headers and then whether they're included or not is represented by whether the checkbox is ticked for each item.