# Dividing items in variable number of groups

Tags: gui-design

In my application, a user gets a list of items and needs to divide these in any number of groups, with some additional restrictions (between X and Y items in a group, etc.) Currently, the application looks roughly like this:

[image: division mockup]

This looks like a clumsy way to do this. For instance, if the user has 6 trucks already and wants to put his last chair in the emptiest truck, he first has to compare them all. Or maybe he wants to play around with different configurations for a bit, which would be much easier if you could move items from one truck to another. Is there a more intuitive approach to this problem?

(Note that the answer to [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22359/good-practice-to-divide-items-into-groups) about dividing items in 2 groups will not work very well, since the number of groups is dynamic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty clunky as the information is repeated across the page. I'd suggest using something like the [OptimalSort](https://www.optimalworkshop.com/optimalsort) card sorting approach: drag and drop into groups, maybe create new groups.

Comment: That looks interesting, I'll see if I can apply that approach to our current contraints. With stuff like that, I'm mostly concerned that it'll take too much space for large lists. Thanks!